# What does this refer to in a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

```
function Box(width, height)
{
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
}

var myBox = new Box(5,5);
```

1. What is the `new` keyword doing here technically? Is it creating a new function? Or is it creating a new object and applying the function to it?
2. If so then this is a way to create a "Box", does this mean the `this` keyword is actually referring to the object myBox?

Comment: See here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Comment: basic principles of object oriented programming. better find a good starters guide to oop

Comment: I'm voting to close this as not a real question because it's a little too broad IMO.

Comment: @Sharky meh... This is JavaScript, "normal" OOP doesn't apply here imo. Valid question methinks.

Comment: @zzzzBov I read the question as being specific to that example code. But I'm still looking for a duplicate.

Comment: @LewsTherin i dont think OP has reached the level of being able to discuss if javascript is truly OOP or not. he doesnt know what "this" represents.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal

Comment: Voted to reopen it. I think the question just needed a bit of order.

Comment: @Sharky The OP clearly has some idea of what `this` should do. What he needs is clarification: "applying `new` to a function call creates an object in JavaScript.. blah blah". Shrugs.

Comment: @LewsTherin, I still disagree. It covers a few too many topics, and has been answered by a number of other existing questions. I don't feel that having new answers to this one is necessary.

Comment: I don't think this question is worthy of an `open/close` war. This is basic information that has been explained many times on SO.

Comment: @zzzzBov Sure, but at least "close as duplicate" would be fine. Lead the OP to some answers.. no?

Comment: Not really NARQy at all. (voted to reopen)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's creating a new object, using `Box` as its constructor. The value of `this` *in this case* (when the function is called with the `new` keyword) is the new instance being constructed. This new object will inherit from whatever is defined as `Box.prototype` (the default being `Object.prototype`).

I said *in this case*, because in JavaScript the value of `this` is determined by how the function is called. I recommend reading the [MDN page on `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) for more information.

---

Note: if this question is supposed to be closed, it should have been as a duplicate. Here are some possible duplicate links that might also help you:

- [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)
- [Javascript 'this' value changing, but can't figure out why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562980/javascript-this-value-changing-but-cant-figure-out-why)
- [this value in JavaScript anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670877/this-value-in-javascript-anonymous-function)
- [javascript this object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176209/javascript-this-object)
- [How does "this" keyword work within a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal)