# Why should "this" be assigned to variable in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

often in some jQuery code I see that `this` is assigned to the variable in jQuery and I do not understand the reason for this approach?

**This is an example of a jQuery plugin constructor:**

```
    //constructor
    function Nullpoll(element, options){
        var widget = this;
         widget.config = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
         widget.element = element;

         widget.element.on( "click", function() {
            alert("Test")
           });

         widget.element.one("change", function(e){
           widget.element.find("button").removeProp("disabled");
         });

         this.init();
        }
```

Comment: Because, in this case, inside the listeners `this` is not the `widget` but the `widget.element`. Declaring it on top is more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `this` is determined by how the function it appears in was called.

You assign it to a different variable either:

1. To give it a more informative name *or*
2. (more commonly) so that the *value* is available in a *different function* which has access to the scope of the first function

In this particular case, the anonymous function passed to `widget.element.one()` uses the value of `this` from the call to `Nullpoll`. If it tried to use the `this` keyword, it would get a different value (what that value was would depend on how the `one` function called the anonymous function)

Answer (score 1):

http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/

In JavaScript, as in most object-oriented programming languages, `this` is a special keyword that is used in methods to refer to the object on which a method is being invoked. The value of this is determined using a simple series of steps:

- If the function is invoked using `Function.call()` or `Function.apply()`, `this` will be set to the first argument passed to `.call()`/`.apply()`. If the first argument passed to `.call()`/`.apply()` is `null` or `undefined`, `this` will refer to the global object (which is the `window` object in web browsers).
- If the function being invoked was created using `Function.bind()`, `this` will be the first argument that was passed to `.bind()` at the time the function was created.
- If the function is being invoked as a method of an object, `this` will refer to that object.
- Otherwise, the function is being invoked as a standalone function not attached to any object, and `this` will refer to the global object.

Comment: This answer describes `this`, but doesn't answer the OP's question about why `this` is being assigned to a variable in their code.

Answer (score 1):

When using inline callbacks within your scope (such as the event handlers in your example), the value of `this` within the callbacks is often not the same as the parent scope.  So, if you want access to the value of `this` in the parent scope from within those callbacks, then it is a common design pattern to save it to a local variable in the parent scope.  Then, within the callbacks, you can still refer to that value from the parent scope even though `this` may have a different value within the callback.

As a secondary benefit, some minimizers can make smaller code by using a local variable rather than `this` because a local variable can be renamed to a single character variable by the minimizer, but `this` cannot be renamed.

Similar question with a bunch of answers here: [What is the value of var me = this;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436709/what-is-the-value-of-var-me-this)

Answer (score -1):

`this` points to the element on the page that a specific method is being invoked on!

refer to http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/